# Why is my database migration not doing anything?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

When I run my migrations, it doesn't do anything:

```
➔ python db_control.py db upgrade
INFO  [alembic.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
```